# Can I make a loop for each instance of an object?

Tags: java, loops, collision-detection

I have lots of instances of an object "Block", I need to add a collision detection to see if my sprite has touched a block. But having to copy and paste and edit each of the code would take to much time as I will have about 200 blocks on each level... here it the collision detection, is there any way possible to make a loop so all the blocks get assigned and the values change so for the first one for eg will be 'block.bottomry' for the first one and then 'block2.bottomry' for the second and for the third 'block3.bottomry' and so on till all the blocks are gone. Here's part of the code:

```
public void iscollided() {
        // bottom right touching block?
        if (sprite.bottomrx < block.bottomrx && sprite.bottomrx > block.bottomlx && sprite.bottomry < block.bottommy && sprite.bottomry > block.topry ){
                Log.d(TAG, "Collided!!!!!!!!!!!!1");


        }

        // bottom left touching block?
        if (sprite.bottomlx < block.bottomrx && sprite.bottomlx > block.bottomlx && sprite.bottomly < block.bottommy && sprite.bottomly > block.topry ){
            Log.d(TAG, "Collided!!!!!!!!!!!!1");


        }
        // top right touching block?
        if (sprite.toprx < block.bottomrx && sprite.toprx > block.bottomlx && sprite.topry < block.bottommy && sprite.topry > block.topry ){
            Log.d(TAG, "Collided!!!!!!!!!!!!1");


        }
        //top left touching block?
        if (sprite.toprx < block.bottomrx && sprite.toprx > block.bottomlx && sprite.topry < block.bottommy && sprite.topry > block.topry ){
            Log.d(TAG, "Collided!!!!!!!!!!!!1");


        }
```

Comment: It looks like you should consider storing your blocks in a [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sure :) you can add the blocks into a list data structure, and loop through the list checking each one.

```
public class Foo {

    private SpecialSprite sprite = new SpecialSprite();
    private List<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();

    public void addBlocks() {

        blocks.add(new Block(...));
        blocks.add(new Block(...));
        blocks.add(new Block(...));
    }

    public void isCollided() {

        for(Block block : blocks) {

            // collision detection for each block.
            if(sprite.bottomrx < block.bottomrx ... ) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Collided!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: More specific example.

Answer (score 0):

What I get from you question is that Blocks are fixed and sprite is moving/floating. Since Blocks are fixed you can put them in an array and put this collision logic inside the for-each loop.

Another point is that a Block can be above, below, ahead or behind the sprite and collision logic will be different in each case. In the block object you can set the position and check that too in for-each loop.

I guess the array of Blocks will be updated with Block in view at runtime, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want is called a "factory method", which creates the block and "registers" it. Here's the code that will do it (I've left out all code not directly relevant to the answer and used `...` where you might have to fill stuff in):

```
public class Block {

    private static final List<Block> BLOCKS = new ArrayList<Block>();

    // A private constructor means everyone has to go through `create()`,
    // which is what you want so they all get registered
    private Block(...) {
        ...
    }

    public static Block create(...) {
        Block block = new Block(...);
        BLOCKS.add(block);
    }

    public static boolean hasCollided(Sprite sprite) {
        for (Block block : BLOCKS) {
            if (sprite.bottomlx < block.bottomrx && sprite.bottomlx > block.bottomlx && sprite.bottomly < block.bottommy && sprite.bottomly > block.topry ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever you create a `Block`, use the `Block.create()` method (this means the new Block gets registered)
Whenever you want to check if a sprite has collided, use `if (Block.hasCollided(someSprite))`